# Changes Hostname on FreeBSD 10

Tags: freebsd, hostname

I've tried changing the hostname on my FreeBSD box.

Changed it in rc.conf, dhclient.conf and tried to set it manually but it still uses the old one. Also samba uses the old one despite its settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

Change the hostname in:

/etc/hostname
/etc/mailname
/etc/postfix/main.cf
/etc/hosts

and then run the command:

hostname -F /etc/hostname

Comment: "hostname -F /etc/hostname " fails "hostname: illegal option -- F
usage: hostname [-fs] [name-of-host]". /etc/hostname /etc/mailname /etc/postfix/main.cf doent exists by default and I already changed the name in etc/hosts so thanks for your answer but it doesnt help at all.

Comment: The command should be "hostname -f /etc/hostname", note the small case 'f' as the parameter.